# Core Text - Line Numbers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-text

How would I add line numbers to Core Text say in a view down the left hand side?

I'm not looking for exact details just how to know where each line starts and ends so I can deduce where to add the numbers in the separate view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're laying out the text using `CTFramesetter`, then you can call `CTFrameGetLineOrigins` on your frame. Each origin represents the start of the baseline for that line. Keep in mind that Core Text uses the Quartz coordinate system, where Y increases from bottom to top.

Comment: That sounds promising, by looking at the method it seems it requires a buffer to store the origins into. I used this simple declaration for it `CGPoint origins;`. How can I loop through all of the origins?

Comment: @Joshua If you call `CTFrameGetLines`, then you get an array of the lines themselves. A simple one-liner to count the lines would be: `CFIndex count = CFArrayGetCount(CTFrameGetLines(frame));`. Then you'd declare `CGPoint* origins = (CGPoint*) malloc(count * sizeof(CGPoint));` to get an appropriate buffer. Don't forget to `free` the buffer when you're done with it.